# How to sort a list of strings in alphabetical order?

Tags: sorting

I have a list of strings:

```
listOfStrings = {"dog", "zebra", "donkey", "anteater", "fish"};
```

How do I sort them in alphabetical order such that the output is:

```
{"anteater", "dog", "donkey", "fish", "zebra"}
```

Attempt:

```
SortBy[{"dog", "zebra", "donkey", "anteater", "fish"}, AlphabeticOrder]
```

Comment: `SortBy[list, "Alphabetical"]` or `SortBy[list, "AlphabeticalOrder"]` or `SortBy[list, "Canonical"]`

Comment: `AlphabeticSort[listOfStrings, CaseOrdering -> "UpperFirst", 
 IgnoreCase -> False]` and throw in a few capitalized entries to see the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sort[{"dog", "zebra", "donkey", "anteater", "fish"}]`

Well, that one works.